# Select Field with foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

_Edit post, English now.

I'm having an "Undefined variable" error when trying to bring cities available in my costumers creation form

I created a method in my controller to search for cities

```
public function cidadesDiponiveis() {
$cidades = Cidade::pluck('descr_mun','id');
return view('cliente/add', compact('cidades'));
}
```

And in the view I'm trying to load the cities within a select field

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cli_municipio">Municipio Teste:</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="cidade_id">
  @foreach($cidades as $cidade)
    <option value="{{$cidade->id}}"> {{$cidade->descr_mun}} </option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
```

But i get the error:

Undefined variable: cidades (View: C:\wamp64\www\erp-laravel\resources\views\cliente\add.blade.php)
in a1b180c4ff9af471667a5d429f9a8f90cb4a1e4b.php (line 57)

Comment: This question is off topic here, because this is an English language site and it's not written in English. You may have better luck asking at http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Can you show us `dd($cidades)` in your controller?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not in English.

Comment: It would be useful to include the error; is it complaining about `$cidades`, or about one of its attributes (e.g., `$cidades->id`)?

Comment: Undefined variable: cidades (View: C:\wamp64\www\erp-laravel\resources\views\cliente\add.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Does it work without using compact?:

```
public function cidadesDiponiveis() {
  $cidades = Cidade::pluck('descr_mun','id');
  return view('cliente/add', ['cidades' => $cidades]);
}
```

Edit - Also make sure that you are getting results from your query and that `$cidades` is not empty.

Comment: Same error. And how i see if it's no empy?

Comment: `dd($cidades);` in your controller before returning the view so we can see what's being returned from the database

Comment: i get same error :/

Comment: You shouldn't get the same error if you execute `dd` right after querying the database: `$cidades = Cidade::pluck('descr_mun','id');` Right after this line add a line with `dd($cidades);` It will show you the contents of `$cidades` variable at that point